# Dictionary.TryGetValue and possible 'null' warning

Tags: c#, nullable, nullable-reference-types

I can't seem to wrap my head around the compiler's warning in this case:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

#nullable enable
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Guid guid = Guid.NewGuid();
        
        Dictionary<Guid, string> d = new();
        
        bool found = d.TryGetValue(guid, out string? str);
        
        if (found is false)
        {
            return;
        }
        
        string s = str; // WARNING: possible null value
    }
}
```

After all, I'm doing the `found` check and return if there is no value (e.g. when the `out str` value is null). Plus, the `out` parameter of the `.TryGetValue` method is annotated with `[MaybeNullWhen(false)]`.

Would appreciate your help figuring our where I'm wrong in my expectations and fixing the code, thanks. Code is [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/eEJk39).

Comment: `if (found is false)` are you sure it is the same as `if (found == false)`?

Comment: The compiler isn't currently capable of doing flow analysis through the `found` variable (although I think that's improving in C# 10, but I can't find the issue right now). Use `if (!d.TryGetValue(guid, out string? str)) { return; }`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Basically the compiler (or language specification) isn't "smart" enough to carry the conditional processing of the return value from `TryGetValue` over when you use a local variable.

If you inline the `TryGetValue` call into the `if` condition, it's fine:

```cs
if (!d.TryGetValue(guid, out string? str))
{
    return;
}
        
string s = str; // No warning
```

It's possible that over time this will evolve to be more sophisticated, but it's relatively difficult to specify this sort of thing in a bullet-proof way.

This isn't limited to nullable reference types - there are other cases where logically code is fine from a human perspective, but the compiler will reject it. For example:

```cs
string text;
bool condition = DateTime.UtcNow.Hour == 5;
if (condition)
{
    text = "hello";
}
if (condition)
{
    Console.WriteLine(text); // Error: use of unassigned local variable
}
```

*We* know that if we get into the second `if` statement body, we'll also have gone into the first one so `text` will have been assigned a value, but the rules of the compiler don't attempt to be smart enough to spot that.

Comment: Omg, I could swear I had tried inlining the check.. ) Must have done smth else wrong. Thank you, sir, appreciate your clarifications!